# Is RestartManager required for Inno Setup CloseApplications?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup 5.5.9.  My installer includes the settings:

```
[Setup]
RestartApplications=no
CloseApplications=force
```

When I run the installer it identifies an application as still running and correctly shows the "The following applications are using files..." page.  I choose to "Automatically close...", but nothing happens - the application remains running.  I see these in my log file:

```
RestartManager found an application using one of our files: {redacted}
Can use RestartManager to avoid reboot? Yes (0)
CurStepChanged(1) called
```

Must the application register with the restart manager to auto close, even though I have specified 'no' for RestartApplications?

Comment: No, the application does not need to register to get closed.